# mySQL join table duplicate issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 table (pcgroup and client pc). Let say the date today is 24/11, I need to find which PC is online and which pc is not online for the last 2 days using only mySQL.

```
INSERT INTO pcgroup(id, groupName) 
  VALUES(1, 'defaultGroup');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) 
  VALUES(1, 1, 'pc1', '2011-11-24');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) 
  VALUES(2, 1, 'pc2', '2011-11-24');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) 
  VALUES(3, 1, 'pc3', '2011-11-20');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) 
  VALUES(4, 1, 'pc4', '2011-11-20');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) 
  VALUES(5, 1, 'pc5', '2011-11-20');
```

Here is my query for now

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  pcgroup.id AS pcGroupID, pcgroup.groupName,
  online.onlinePC, offline.offlinePC
FROM
  (
    SELECT   
      pcgroup.Id, pcGroup.groupName
    FROM
      pcgroup
    WHERE
      (pcgroup.Id = 1)
  ) pcgroup
LEFT  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      clientpc.Id, clientpc.pcGroupId, clientpc.clientPcName AS onlinePC
    FROM
      clientpc
    WHERE
      DateDiff(CURDATE(),clientpc.lastOnlineTime) <= 2
    AND
      DateDiff(CURDATE(),clientpc.lastOnlineTime) IS NOT NULL
  ) online  
 ON 
  pcgroup.Id = online.pcGroupId
 LEFT JOIN
   (
     SELECT
       clientpc.Id, clientpc.pcGroupId, clientpc.clientPcName AS offlinePC
     FROM
       clientpc
     WHERE
       (DateDiff(CURDATE(),clientpc.lastOnlineTime) > 2
     OR
        DateDiff(CURDATE(),clientpc.lastOnlineTime) IS NULL)
   ) offline 
  ON pcgroup.Id = offline.pcGroupId
```

This is the result I get

```
*pcGroupID    groupName        onlinePC       offlinePC*
  1           defaultGroup      pc1             pc3
  1           defaultGroup      pc1             pc4
  1           defaultGroup      pc1             pc5
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc3
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc4
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc5
```

However, what I need is something like this

```
*pcGroupID    groupName        onlinePC       offlinePC*
  1           defaultGroup      pc1             pc3
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc4
  1           defaultGroup                      pc5
```

So my question is, is that achievable? and if yes, how. Have been working on this query for 2 days. So i really appreciate if you guys can help me out.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that? Are you trying to do a presentation logic in SQL? What happens when (in your example) `pc1` and `pc3` belong to a different group? Why is `pc1` in the same row with `pc3` and not (e.g.) `pc4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use 2 simple queries and do the presentation in your application?:

```
 --- Online ---
 SELECT
     c.pcGroupID, p.groupName, c.clientPcName, 'Online' AS pcStatus
 FROM
     pcgroup AS g
   JOIN
     clientpc AS c
       ON g.Id = c.pcGroupId
 WHERE
     g.Id = @pcGroupIdToBeChecked
   AND
     c.lastOnlineTime >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY

 --- Offline ---
 SELECT
     c.pcGroupID, p.groupName, c.clientPcName, 'Offline' AS pcStatus
 FROM
     pcgroup AS g
   JOIN
     clientpc AS c
       ON g.Id = c.pcGroupId
 WHERE
     g.Id = @pcGroupIdToBeChecked
   AND
     ( c.lastOnlineTime < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 2 DAY
      OR
       c.lastOnlineTime IS NULL
     )
```

Answer (score 2):

I fired up a MySQL instance and simulated the rowid used in the Postgres solution. Creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE pcgroup(id int, groupName varchar(64));
CREATE TABLE clientpc(id int, pcGroupId int, clientPcName varchar(64), lastOnlineTime date);

INSERT INTO pcgroup(id, groupName) VALUES(1, 'defaultGroup');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(1, 1, 'pc1', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(2, 1, 'pc2', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(3, 1, 'pc3', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(4, 1, 'pc4', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(5, 1, 'pc5', CURRENT_DATE-4);

INSERT INTO pcgroup(id, groupName) VALUES(2, 'group2');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(6, 2, 'pc6', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(7, 2, 'pc7', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(8, 2, 'pc8', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(9, 2, 'pc9', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(10, 2, 'pc10', CURRENT_DATE);
```

The script (follows same logic as the Postgres solution):

```
-- Apply sort to union
SELECT pcGroupID, groupName, onlinePC, offlinePC
  FROM (
        SELECT online.pcGroupID, online.groupName, online.clientPcName AS onlinePC, IFNULL(offline.clientPcName, '-') AS offlinePC

          FROM (-- Apply a groupName-based row number to the list of "online" PCs
                SELECT pcGroupID, groupName, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime
                      ,if(@lastGroupID!=pcGroupID
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := 1)
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := @curRow + 1)) AS row_number
                          ,@lastGroupID := pcGroupID
                  FROM (-- Filter to the list of online PCs
                        SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName, c.lastOnlineTime
                          FROM pcgroup g
                              ,clientpc c
                          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                            AND c.lastOnlineTime >= CURRENT_DATE - 2
                          ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName ) x
                      ,(SELECT @curRow := 0) r ) AS online

               LEFT OUTER JOIN (

                -- Apply a groupName-based row number to the list of "offline" PCs
                SELECT pcGroupID, groupName, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime
                      ,if(@lastGroupID!=pcGroupID
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := 1)
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := @curRow + 1)) AS row_number
                          ,@lastGroupID := pcGroupID
                  FROM (-- Filter to the list of offline PCs
                        SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName, c.lastOnlineTime
                          FROM pcgroup g
                              ,clientpc c
                          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                            AND c.lastOnlineTime < CURRENT_DATE - 2
                          ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName ) x
                      ,(SELECT @curRow := 0) r ) AS offline

            ON (online.row_number = offline.row_number)


UNION

        SELECT offline.pcGroupID, offline.groupName, IFNULL(online.clientPcName, '~') AS onlinePC, offline.clientPcName AS offlinePC

          FROM (-- Apply a groupName-based row number to the list of "online" PCs
                SELECT pcGroupID, groupName, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime
                      ,if(@lastGroupID!=pcGroupID
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := 1)
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := @curRow + 1)) AS row_number
                          ,@lastGroupID := pcGroupID
                  FROM (-- Filter to the list of online PCs
                        SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName, c.lastOnlineTime
                          FROM pcgroup g
                              ,clientpc c
                          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                            AND c.lastOnlineTime >= CURRENT_DATE - 2
                          ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName ) x
                      ,(SELECT @curRow := 0) r ) AS online

               RIGHT OUTER JOIN (

                -- Apply a groupName-based row number to the list of "offline" PCs
                SELECT pcGroupID, groupName, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime
                      ,if(@lastGroupID!=pcGroupID
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := 1)
                          ,CONCAT_WS('_', pcGroupID, @curRow := @curRow + 1)) AS row_number
                          ,@lastGroupID := pcGroupID
                  FROM (-- Filter to the list of offline PCs
                        SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName, c.lastOnlineTime
                          FROM pcgroup g
                              ,clientpc c
                          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                            AND c.lastOnlineTime < CURRENT_DATE - 2
                          ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName ) x
                      ,(SELECT @curRow := 0) r ) AS offline

            ON (online.row_number = offline.row_number)

    ) z ORDER BY pcGroupID, groupName, OnlinePC, offlinePC
```

And the result:

```
1   defaultGroup  pc1    pc3
1   defaultGroup  pc2    pc4
1   defaultGroup  ~      pc5
2   group2        pc10   pc6
2   group2        pc8    pc7
2   group2        pc9    -
```

-- Postgresql --

I tried it out in Postgres.  The query looks more frightening then it really is. There are a number of features which would shorten this up: subquery factoring (ie using WITH), a pseduo row number generator, full outer joins). I'm not sure if mysql has that, so I didn't use those functions.

I think the main point is that you are asking for two distinct lists that are not really related: onlinePCs and offlinePCs. You just want to put the two lists side by side. TO do this, you can introduce a row count pseudo column to create a relation between the two lists. Step 1 generates the list of online PCs and counts how many there are for each group (generates the a row identifier which is _. It then joins it to a list of offline PCs based on this row identifier. If there were more offline PCs than online PCs, the offline PCs would not show up in this list. That is why we do the entire thing again in step 4, but this time driven by the offline PCs in order to account for the case where there are more offline PCs than online PCs. The UNION will get rid of duplicates.

I also used CURRENT_DATE and hardcoded the 2 as the number of days between offline and online. You will need to play with that.

The creation script:

```
CREATE TABLE pcgroup(id bigint, groupName varchar);
CREATE TABLE clientpc(id bigint, pcGroupId bigint, clientPcName varchar, lastOnlineTime date);

INSERT INTO pcgroup(id, groupName) VALUES(1, 'defaultGroup');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(1, 1, 'pc1', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(2, 1, 'pc2', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(3, 1, 'pc3', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(4, 1, 'pc4', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(5, 1, 'pc5', CURRENT_DATE-4);

INSERT INTO pcgroup(id, groupName) VALUES(2, 'group2');
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(6, 2, 'pc6', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(7, 2, 'pc7', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(8, 2, 'pc8', CURRENT_DATE-4);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(9, 2, 'pc9', CURRENT_DATE);
INSERT INTO clientpc(id, pcGroupId, clientPcName, lastOnlineTime) VALUES(10, 2, 'pc10', CURRENT_DATE);
```

The query:

```
SELECT online.pcGroupID, online.groupName, online.clientPcName AS onlinePC, offline.clientPcName AS offlinePC

    -- 1: Get the list of online PCs, and give them a group based pseudo rownumber
  FROM (SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName
              ,g.id || '_' || row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY g.id ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName) AS rownum
          FROM pcgroup g
              ,clientpc c
          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
            AND lastOnlineTime > CURRENT_DATE - 2) AS online

    -- 2: Get the list of offline PCs, and give them a group based pseudo rownumber
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName
                              ,g.id || '_' || row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY g.id ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName) AS rownum
                         FROM pcgroup g
                             ,clientpc c
                         WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                           AND lastOnlineTime <= CURRENT_DATE - 2) AS offline

       -- 3: Join the list together: this will only include rows for the number of "online" pcs that exist
       ON (online.rownum = offline.rownum)

-- 4: Repeat 1-3, but this time base it on offline pcs and it will only include rows for the number of "offline" pcs that exist
--    The UNION will dump the duplicates

UNION

SELECT offline.pcGroupID, offline.groupName, online.clientPcName AS onlinePC, offline.clientPcName AS offlinePC
  FROM (SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName
              ,g.id || '_' || row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY g.id ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName) AS rownum
          FROM pcgroup g
              ,clientpc c
          WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
            AND lastOnlineTime > CURRENT_DATE - 2) AS online

       RIGHT OUTER JOIN (SELECT g.id AS pcGroupID, g.groupName, c.clientPcName
                              ,g.id || '_' || row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY g.id ORDER BY g.id, c.clientPcName) AS rownum
                         FROM pcgroup g
                             ,clientpc c
                         WHERE c.pcGroupId = g.id
                           AND lastOnlineTime <= CURRENT_DATE - 2) AS offline
       ON (online.rownum = offline.rownum)
```

The result:

```
 pcgroupid |  groupname   | onlinepc | offlinepc
-----------+--------------+----------+-----------
         1 | defaultGroup | pc1      | pc3
         1 | defaultGroup | pc2      | pc4
         1 | defaultGroup |          | pc5
         2 | group2       | pc10     | pc6
         2 | group2       | pc8      | pc7
         2 | group2       | pc9      |
(6 rows)
```

Comment: I tried to re do the query in mysql, however i got slightly different results where my default group displays 6 rows as pc3, pc4, and pc5 display in a new line in offlinepc column after pc1 and pc2. The offlinepc fields beside pc1 and pc2 are null. Anyways, this  answer get a vote up from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Use group by in mysql as follow

```
GROUP BY offlinePC;
```

You can get following result.

```
*pcGroupID    groupName        onlinePC       offlinePC*
  1           defaultGroup      pc1             pc3
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc4
  1           defaultGroup      pc2             pc5
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do a presentation logic in SQL. If you need to format the data in a certain way, do it in your client language. SQL is for retrieving and manipulating data, not formatting!

BTW, since you don't actually want to *filter* rows in any way, and just want to *classify* them, you can simply `SELECT * FROM clientpc`, then decide how to present each row to the user based on the difference between the current date and `lastOnlineTime`.

*(You can also easily JOIN `clientpc` with `pcgroup`, but even that migh be unnecessary since you are going to fetch most, if not all rows from `pcgroup` anyway, so a client-side "join" and/or "group" in the context of your UI might be more appropriate.)*